# Decal Applied in Shader Node Only Rendered When Close

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I have a number of decals I'm applying with shader nodes to a procedural texture.
[image]
The decals render properly when inspecting them closely and stop rendering completely as I move the camera or viewport away.

Close

[image: Close]

Medium

[image: Medium]

Far? Not even that far away

[image: Far? Not even that far away]

I have another decal setup that doesn't have any procedural wear that seems to render from far away just fine. I've used the decals that don't render properly in this way and they still exhibit the same behavior.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Haskell, do you think some of the information we might need is concealed inside those node-groups? Maybe.. maybe not. Sharing your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ might help, here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the texture interpolation for the image in a node group.
Changing from Linear to Closest fixed the rendering problem.

[image]